# Cannot display date_field in a content view

Tags: views, datetime

Without succes i am trying to display a date_field in a content view (so no fields view).
I rather dont want a fields view as i dont want to theme the whole view.
The view is displaying other fields such as image_field etc.

I have checked the:/types/manage/mycontenttype/display settings for default as for teaser.
But in both settings they are set to default (so no hidden)

The normal display of the node itself displays the date fine.
With a fields display i can render the date_field as well.

Does somebody has any thought why the date_field is not displaying in a content view?

D7

Comment: Are you trying to display the date field or trying to add that field as a filter?

Comment: I am trying to display the field. My filter is content:mycontenttype